# Display alert from custom cell in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swift3

I have designed custom cells in `listViewCell.swift` and `listViewCell.xib`. In which i have textfield. When the user enters a number more than 100 then i want to show alert.
I have tableView in HomeViewController.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(
    title: "Error", 
    message: "Please Insert value less than 100",
    preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert
)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
    title: "Click", 
    style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, 
    handler: nil
))
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

then it gives me `Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f945a5a67d0> on <ProjName.LoginController: 0x7f945a407e70> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

and when i change the code to

```
let alert = UIAlertController(
    title: "Error", message: "Please Insert value less than 100",
    preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert
)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
    title: "Click", 
    style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, 
    handler: nil
))
HomeViewController().present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

then it gives me `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`
and points to

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    **tableViewList.delegate = self**
    tableViewList.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
}
```

How can i show a alert from a custom cell? or how can we create a common alert function in HomeViewController and show it form any swift file?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: at which line you got this error ?

Comment: Does your tableview and alert is on same HomeController? If so instead of HomeViewController(), why don't you try self. present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: I got error at `tableViewList.delegate = self`

Answer (score 1):

You could go with making delegates of your custom cell. Set the delegate of your custom cells, let's say `didEnterInvalidValue` `didEnterValidValue`, to your `HomeViewController`. From those delegate implementations, show your `UIAlertController` with custom messages.

Or you can iterate over your `self.navigationController?.viewControllers` to find the top view controller and show `UIAlertController` on that view controller's view.

Comment: I created a delegate called didEnterInvalidValue

added `cell.didEnterInvalidValue = self as? customProtocol1` in tableView cellForRowAt function

outside the function i wrote display alert function
`func displayAlert ( title: String){
        print("This line prints")
    }`

Outside Class i declared the custom protocol to call the function 
`protocol customProtocol1{
    func displayAlert(title: String)
}`

Comment: in listViewCell.swift
i added `var didEnterInvalidValue: customProtocol1?` in the class

then i'm calling `didEnterInvalidValue?.displayAlert(title: "Error")` after validation

But still don't executes the DisplayAlert function. Can you please help me by telling where i'm going wrong? i'm new to swift

Comment: Well you need to study delegates for it first. Go through this link :
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/swift-from-scratch-delegation-and-properties--cms-23445

Answer (score 0):

Most easiest would be

**Step 1:**

From your View controller where you have used your custom Cell, make a common delegate function for your textField which purpose is to notify you about text length.
You may need to extend UITextFieldDelegate for this.

Or u can assign a target function to your textField(Not sure if it works though)

**How do you catch Specific TextField?**

You need to assign a tag for every textField using indexPath and catch that specific textField using that tag.

**Step 2:**

In that function you can show your alert by only using

```
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the delegate answer. But for a faster solution, at several projects I create a singleton from the rootViewController (generally the UINavigationController) at AppDelegate so it can get the rootController any time. Using keyWindow, it's not very recommended since the keyWindow it's not always the one controlled by who, for example, alert dialog redefine it.

Another projects I create a AlertClass singletone, where it's initialised by the rootController, and it's always invoked from it.